# Can i add new label called looker-context-look_id in BigQuery connection(Looker)

Tags: python, google-bigquery, looker

I wanna see my look id in corresponding bigquey job labels. My objective is to efficiently track Looker queries within BigQuery. Could you please provide guidance on achieving this integration?